# Xcode 7.2: Failed to Locate or generated signing assets, Wild Card App IDs can not be used to create In House Provisioning Profiles

Tags: xcode7, watchkit, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning, ios9.2

I signed an iOS App and WatchKit App & Extension targets with valid provisioning profiles (Separate provisioning profile for each app identifier, and not wild card App ID), Build was archived successfully but when I try to export/save Enterprise build, Xcode auto generate/locate XC: provisioning profile and it also and resets/invalidates previously selected provisioning profiles.  I get below error. (even though we are not using Wild Card App IDs)

**"Failed to Locate or generated signing assets, Wild Card App IDs can not be used to create In House Provisioning Profiles".**

[image]

Comment: Is it that you *used* to use a wildcard app ID for development and it's using that one despite your changes or is it that you *never* used a wildcard app ID and it insists that you have one?

Comment: @BSMP, I'm not using wildcard App ID at all.  and i am archiving app for Enterprise Distribution  (with distribution profile specific to App Identifier).

This seems to be a bug of Xcode 7.2.  I've fixed the issue after hours of troubleshooting. I've posted answer below with detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like it is bug in Xcode 7.2 ,  after trying multiple times and troubleshooting , below solution worked for me.

1) Open Xcode preference

2) Select the team

3) Click the "View Details.."

4) In section "Provisioning Profiles": Right Click on any profile and Show in Finder and Delete All Provisioning Profiles in that folder.

5) In section "Provisioning Profiles". Click on "Download All".

6) Restart the Xcode.

7) Select Team in General, and Provisioning Profiles in Build Settings and archive build again.

For more detail find Screenshots below:

**1) Open Xcode preference,**

[image]

**2) Select the team,**
[image]

**3) Click the "View Details..".**

**4) In section "Provisioning Profiles": Right Click on any profile and Show in Finder and Delete All Provisioning Profiles in that folder.**

[image]

**Delete Provisioning Profiles**
[image]

**5) In section "Provisioning Profiles". Click on "Download All".**

[image]

**6) Restart the Xcode.** (most of the times Restarting Xcode is only solution after downloading new provisioning profiles or after changing App identifiers)

**7) Select Team in General, and Provisioning Profiles in Build Settings and archive build again.**

Hope it solves your problem. :)

P.S: I've also opened a bug to Apple via Apple Bug Reporter.

Comment: I fell victim of this **and** the expired WWDR certificate thing too. You solved half my problem, thank you! ;)

Comment: Thank you so much for posting this. My co-workers were starting to complain about all the curse words coming from my desk as I tried to build my app for in-house distribution.