# XCode export app, wildcard error

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am developing a Swift iOS app for in-house distribution and I am having trouble exporting the app - I get:  "**Wildcard App IDs can not be used to create In House provisioning profiles.  Please use an Explicit App ID.**"

[image: Wildcard Error Message]

In the Member Center, I have created an explicit App ID:
[image: explicit App ID]

In the Member Center, I have also created an iOS Provisioning Profile for Distribution:
[image: iOS Provisioning Profile]

In XCode, I have downloaded the distribution provisioning profile (under preferences > Accounts):
[image: Account screen]

This is a Swift iOS app (my first) and I am trying to export the app (.ipa & .plist file), so that I can deploy it from an Intranet site.  Note: I do not have an MDM (nor do I want to purchase one at this time).  Xcode version: 7.2.1.

What am I missing?

**Edit 2/15/2016:** This [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35251324/xcode-7-2-failed-to-locate-or-generated-signing-assets-wild-card-app-ids-can-n) is about a similar issue, but the steps outlined there did not resolve the issue for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode 7.2: Failed to Locate or generated signing assets, Wild Card App IDs can not be used to create In House Provisioning Profiles](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35251324/xcode-7-2-failed-to-locate-or-generated-signing-assets-wild-card-app-ids-can-n)

Comment: @BSMP The steps outlined there did not resolve the issue for me.

Comment: Check the following, its possible your a victim of Apple's WWDR cert expiring 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/999313/iphone-app-signing-a-valid-signing-identity-matching-this-profile-could-not-be?rq=1

Comment: Also you could check your CodeSigning Identity & Provisioning Profile settings in your build settings (in Xcode click the Project File > Build Settings)

Comment: @CStreel You're the man!!!  That was it - after deleting the expired cert, the export worked fine!  If you put it as an Answer, I can accept it.  Apple owes me some hair!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I faced the same problem and almost spent one day to solve the problem.

When I encountered the problem, I thought it was an error related with invalid distribution certificate or provisioning profile. I renewed certificates and all other stuff. Nothing worked! Neither certificates nor provisioning profiles were the root cause.

I have seen an [announcement](https://developer.apple.com/support/certificates/expiration/) on Apple Developer page. Apple's WWDR Certificate was expiring and newest one available on that page. I updated that certificate and it worked!

Steps you should follow:

1. Open `Keychain Access` and remove expired `Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority` from certificates.
2. Download new certificate as suggested.
3. Be sure that `Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority` is located under `Systems` keychain, **not in login**.
4. Open `XCode` (If already, close and then open)
5. Clean your project.
6. Select your valid signing certificates and provisioning profiles. (You don't need to refresh your certificates or profiles as annoucement suggested)
7. Hit Archive button!

Hope this may help someone else.