# Problems with InHouse distribution

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing, in-house-distribution

I try to distribute my app using an apple enterprise account but encounter a really weird problem.

In apple developer portal I first created an App-ID with an explicit bundle identifier (I already have a distribution-certificate so there was no need to add something):

[image: App with explicit App-ID]

After this I created a distribution provisioning profile for InHouse distribution using the previously generated App-ID (with explicit bundle-ID):

[image: InHouse Profile]

Than I downloaded the profile and installed it.

In XCode I made sure, that my project uses the correct Bundle-Identifier:

[image: Set Bundle Identifier in info and build settings]

And of course I set the code signing settings to my previously generated distribution profile (using the App-ID with explizit Bundle-Identifier)

[image: Set InHouse Provisioning Profile]

After everything was set I generated an archive and opened it in the organizer.
In the organizer I checked the details and even here the correct Bundle ID is displayed:

[image: Bundle ID in Archive Details viewed in organizer after export]

But if I try to export the archive I get following error:

[image: Error: Wildcard App IDs can not be used to create InHouse provisioning profiles]

I really don't get it. I don't even have a wildcard App ID in my enterprise account. I would very much appreciate every hint or suggestion.

THANK YOU!!!

Comment: did you have a same App IDs or App names even in-house distribution or not in your account?

Comment: If your App ID is same as an existing App ID and it is a new app, you cannot distribute it. You should use same App profile to do development. **Remind:** In production, you cannot distribute a app name which is same as existing App name in your account.

Comment: Thank you for your comment but I don't have another app with the same App ID. I have this app (with this name and bundle ID) only once in my enterprise account and use this app for development and InHouse distribution.

Comment: so you should try to change your bundle ID. I have a revamped app which has this problem before.

Comment: I added a new App-ID with completely new name and bundle id. I added a new InHouse-Distribution profile for this new app, downloaded it and added it in XCode to my project ... sadly to the exactly same effect. I get the same error message.

Comment: do you have any spaces or some special character(except dot) in your IDs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

Thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35421245/xcode-export-app-wildcard-error) I found [this apple announcement](https://developer.apple.com/support/certificates/expiration/) and was able to fix the issue as described:

"Xcode unable to create distribution builds for App Store submissions or Enterprise apps.
This issue occurs when the expired WWDR Intermediate certificate is present in both the System keychain and Login keychain within the Keychain Access application. To resolve the issue, first download and install the renewed certificate. Next, in the Keychain Access application, select the System keychain. Select 'Show Expired Certificates' in the View menu and then delete the expired version of the Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certificate Authority Intermediate certificate. Your certificates should now appear as valid in Keychain Access and be available to Xcode."

Answer (score 0):

Your iTunes accounts (developer & production) & your Enterprise account bundle id should be different. Its can't take same iTunes account bundle id for enterprise account to create in house profile. Thanks :)

Comment: They are different. I even created a completely new App ID with new and never before used Bundle ID and still get this error.