# Wildcard App IDs can not be used to create In House provisioning profiles. Please use an Explicit App ID

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-provisioning, in-house-distribution

I'm invited to a team to build an in house app. I'm granted as a team admin in Apple Developer Portal. The problem is that when I want to export the achieved app to a .ipa, it shows the message "Wildcard App IDs can not be used to create In House provisioning profiles. Please use an Explicit App ID." as the following screenshot. At the beginning, I login to Xcode/Preference/Account and download all provisioning profiles. Then I tried to login another account (who is able to export the .ipa) on Xcode/Preference/Account. Both trial lead to a same error message. Then I reset all my certificates and provisioning profiles on developer portal but in vain.
The interesting thing is that there's always a wildcard app id "*" on the developer portal, I tried to remove it manually but it comes back every time when I try to export the in house app.

I also tried the answers 
[Xcode 7.2: Failed to Locate or generated signing assets, Wild Card App IDs can not be used to create In House Provisioning Profiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35251324/xcode-7-2-failed-to-locate-or-generated-signing-assets-wild-card-app-ids-can-n)
and this one 
[XCode export app, wildcard error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35421245/xcode-export-app-wildcard-error)
, nothing happened.

Any idea? Thanks for reading my question. I've already spend two days on this issue.....
[Screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NuO83.png)

Comment: Just try to refresh the provisional profiles in the keychain and try again

Comment: Have you created an explicit App ID under identifiers, and then generated a provisioning profile using that App ID in Developer Center?

Comment: @sschale Yes, there's always a explicit id in the developer center. I used it to generate a provisioning profile. But once i try to export the ipa, there would be a new wildcard id "*" created automatically.

Comment: @JobinsJohn I tried it but still the same :(

Comment: @Neo Can you check the validity of the certificate and profiles in the keychain. Also check if there are any duplicate certifictes, ie by the same name

Comment: @JobinsJohn I remove all invalid & duplicated certificates and provisioning profiles, then I did it over, the "Wildcard... " error is still there. I found that there's a iPhone Developer certificate named by the other team member is automatically generated in my keychain, not sure if it matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode unable to create distribution builds for App Store submissions or Enterprise apps.

This issue occurs when the expired **WWDR Intermediate certificate** is present in both the System keychain and Login keychain within the Keychain Access application.

**To resolve the issue**, first download and install the renewed certificate.

**Next**, in the *Keychain Access application*, select the *System keychain.*

**Select** *'Show Expired Certificates'* in the View menu and then delete the expired version of the Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certificate Authority Intermediate certificate.

Your certificates should now appear as valid in **Keychain Access** and be available to Xcode. This issue is resolved in OS X El Capitan v10.11.4 beta.

from [developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/support/certificates/expiration/)